# VS code cannot compile mutiple C++ files(WSL)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I just started to setup my VS Code in WSL. I followed by the instruction from GCC on [Windows subsystem for Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl). Most of the work is done, there is only one issue. For this part:

> ## Modifying tasks.json
>
> You can modify your tasks.json to build multiple C++ files by using an argument like `${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp` instead of `${file}`. You can also modify the output filename by replacing `${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}` with a hard-coded filename (for example 'helloworld.out').

I want to compile multiple cpp files, but the method provides from above `${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp` instead of `${file}` doesn't work for me. After I replaced it, the g++ seems like recognize the *.cpp as a file so it can't find it.

This is what the terminal shows.

```
g++: error: /.../.../*.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your tasks.json?

Comment: My task.json is exactly like the one from the instruction, except the {$file} replaced with the ${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out the problem is on the name of my folder. There is a space in my folder name, so change the name of the folder solved this problem. It is really not a good habit to use space. But if you continue to want to use a name that contains space, do *"\"${workspaceFolder}\"/*.cpp"** instead of *"${workspaceFolder}/.cpp"*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead: `"${workspaceFolder}/**.cpp"`

From the website you posted the example `tasks.json` would be this

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "g++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
      "args": ["-g", "${workspaceFolder}/**.cpp", "-o", "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "/usr/bin"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I can't tell you the reasoning behind the double asterix ***** but it takes all the files with .cpp ending in the current folder.

Comment: Thx for your reply, but I still get the same kind of error. like `g++: error: /.../.../**.cpp: No such file or directory`. The *.cpp becomes **.cpp.

Comment: Ye, I also find this solution from another place, but this just doesn't work for me.